# GoFStat error - Replacement has length zero

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I've got this problem using GoFStat under the fitdistrplus package in R.
Here's my code:

```
col = c(2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,4,3,1,4)

fw = fitdist(col, "weibull", lower = c(0,0))
fg = fitdist(col, "gamma", lower = c(0,0))
fln = fitdist(col, "lnorm")

ddlist = list(
  fw,
  fln,
  fg
)

gofstat(ddlist)
```

It gives the error:

> Error in ans[!test & ok] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test & 
>   :    replacement has length zero In addition: Warning message: In
>   rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :   'x' is NULL so the result will
>   be NULL

Any help? Am I doing something dumb?

Thanks

Comment: Try with a different `col` vector, like: `set.seed(1); col = rbinom(10,4, 0.3)+1`: the code works. This proves that the problem is in your data, not in the code.

Comment: Ahh I see, the data I have been using was actually wrong. Thanks for the help.